# How to inject an instance of a class with a parameterized constructor using CDI (Java EE 6 only)

Tags: dependency-injection, java-ee-6, cdi

I'm new to CDI, tried searching for the usage, could not find anything and so posting the question.  I'm trying to figure how I can inject an instance of a class with a parameterized constructor only using CDI.  I'm not using Spring so, how it is done in spring does not help.  Here is a sample I've created to show what's the issue.  My @Inject will not work in this scenario.

```
    public class A 
    {
        public A(boolean deliverFromLocalWarehouse)
        {
            if(deliverFromLocalWarehouse)
            {
                wareHouseId = new Integer(10); 
            }
            else 
            {
                wareHouseId = new Integer(100);
            }
        }

        public void deliver()
        {
            //get wareHouse address by Id and initiate delivery.   
        }

        private Integer wareHouseId = null;
    }

    public class B 
    {

        @Inject
        private A a;
    }
```

Thanks
Srikrishna Kalavacharla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the constructor parameter should come from a bean, I think you can simply annotate it:

```
public A(@Inject boolean localWarehouse) { ...
```

and inject it with

```
@Inject A a;
```

If you want two different instances of A (with different constructor arguments), you could subclass them:

```
public AForLocalWarehouse extends A {
    public AForLocalWarehouse() {
        super(true);
    }
}
```

and inject them with

```
@Inject AForLocalWarehouse a;
```

or use a [producer method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkgkv.html) with [qualifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbck.html):

```
@Produces @LocalWarehouse
public A localWarehouse() { return new A(true); }

@Produces @RemoteWarehouse
public A remoteWarehouse() { return new A(false); }
```

and inject them with

```
@Inject @LocalWarehouse A a;
@Inject @RemoteWarehouse A a;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  You are suggesting changes to class A so that it's possible to inject it.  Question still remains how I can inject.  To be more specific, in class B, instead of @Inject private A a, how would it change?  Thanks for your help again!

Comment: I have added examples for injection as well.

Comment: When I tried the last option, it gives me the error "WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [A] with qualifiers [@ LocalWarehouse] at injection point [[field] @ LocalWarehouse @ Inject com.cdi.test.B.a]"

Comment: Ah, the Java EE tutorial failed to mention that (according to the [CDI spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr299/index.html)) "A producer method must be a non-abstract method of a managed bean class or session bean class. A producer method may
be either static or non-static. If the bean is a session bean, the producer method must be either a business method of the
EJB or a static method of the bean class."

Comment: I've tried option 2 (sub-class) which works, but the problem is I cannot get anything injected into it because I'm creating the instance myself and not letting the container do it for me.  When I tried option 1 (@ Inject parameter), eclipse says it's not valid.